# Is there a better way to fix messed up wpa_supplicant and interfaces files on Windows?

Tags: ssh, pi-zero, windows, wpa-supplicant

Hello I am very new to Raspberry pi having got a Raspi 0 only a few days ago. The only way I know to access any of the code is by ssh-ing from my laptop into the pi, but it worked and I was very happy with it. But then I wanted to go to another house and have the pi automatically connect to both my internet and the other house's. I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mikestreety/use-a-raspberry-pi-with-multiple-wifi-networks-2eda2d39fdd6) and ended up modifying my *wpa_supplicant.conf* and *interfaces* files, only to end up locked out of my pi because I could no longer ssh.

I only have Windows computers so I ended up having to do the following to change the files back to normal:

1. Downloaded virtualbox following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=diIW3fgewhI)
2. Downloaded the virtualbox extension package for my version of virtualbox
3. Partially followed this [tutorial](https://www.centennialsoftwaresolutions.com/post/sd-card-access-from-ubuntu-16-04-3-on-virtualbox-on-windows-7) of how to read an SD card into virtualbox

   - NOTE: the USB SD card reader was required
   - NOTE: my computer never checkmarked the USB, it actually said that an error occured, but when I typed the code *sudo fdisk -l* I could see my USB SD reader
4. I then mounted the card following this [tutorial](https://linuxconfig.org/howto-mount-usb-drive-in-linux) and modified my files before ejecting and celebrating

I ended up fixing my pi and I can now ssh back into it, but this was incredibly annoying to do, and I am wondering if there is a better way that I just missed.

Comment: For most use cases, you never need to mess with `interfaces` file - all you really need to change for accessing wireless is `wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: Shut down your RPi and power off. Pull the SDCard. Insert in your Windows system's card reader and edit `E:\wpa_supplicant.conf` with a good version as per the instructions at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `wpa_supplicant.conf` in the boot partition, and it will overwrite any existing.

You can configure `wpa_supplicant.conf` for multiple networks.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

There is NO WAY to change `interfaces`, but then there is **NO REASON** to ever modify it.
Just delete it - effectively on Stretch and Buster it **does NOTHING**.

NOTE that tutorial you linked is hopelessly **OBSOLETE**, and would perform significantly worse than the default!

*I often wonder why so many seem to find poor tutorials by unknown authors when the Foundation has up to date correct instructions*.

Comment: `boot sector` ... boot partition?

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are better solutions for troubleshooting instead of following four (outdated?) tutorials. One of it is to use a Linux box instead of a MS Windows computer. You can just boot a live CD of one of the popular Distributions like **Debian**, **Ubuntu** or what you like. I would prefer **Debian** because the **Raspberry Pi OS** is a flavor of Debian. Now you can direct access all partitions and files on the SD Card using the card reader and mount the partitions on the SD Card.